# how to get my image slider be responsive in drupal 7?

Tags: css, drupal

I have programmatically added a slider for my drupal website. I also installed a css-editor module since I don't have access to it(it's my partner's server). Anyways, I have tried the @media query but it won't work.

here is what I tried and the actual css code.

```
@media screen and (width: 200px){

  #slider{display:none; !important;}
}

#main-menu-links a
{
    background: #E37222;
}


/************
for slider

*****************/
/* http://www.menucool.com */

#sliderFrame, #sliderFrame div {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
#sliderFrame 
{
    width:600px;
    min-width: 50px;
    margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
}

#slider, #slider .sliderInner {
    width:600px;height:306px;/* Must be the same size as the slider images */
    min-width:50px;
    border-radius:3px;
}

#slider {
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;
}

/* the link style (if an image is wrapped by a link) */
#slider a.imgLink, #slider .video {
    z-index:2;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;
    width:100%;height:100%;
}
#slider .video {
    background:transparent url(video.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

/* Caption styles */
#slider .mc-caption {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px 0;/* 10px will increase the height.*/
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;top:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    font: bold 14px/20px Arial;
    color:#EEE;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#slider .mc-caption a {
    color:#FB0;
}
#slider .mc-caption a:hover {
    color:#DA0;
}


/* ------ built-in navigation bullets wrapper ------*/
#slider .navBulletsWrapper  {
    top:320px;
    text-align:center;
    background:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}

/* each bullet */
#slider .navBulletsWrapper div 
{
    width:11px; height:11px;
    font-size:0;color:White;/*hide the index number in the bullet element*/
    background:transparent url(bullet.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    display:inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1;
    overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer;
    margin:0 6px;/* set distance between each bullet*/
}

#slider .navBulletsWrapper .active {background-position:0 -11px;}


/* --------- Others ------- */

#slider img, #slider>b, #slider a>b {
    position:absolute; border:none; display:none;
}

#slider .sliderInner {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
}

#slider>a, #slider video, #slider audio {display:none;}
#slider div {-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
```

Comment: Which slider are you using?  Many of the packaged sliders out there have responsive functionality in their libraries out-of-the-box and/or module counterparts (i.e. Flex Slider Module, Owl Carousel Module).

Comment: it's a jsImg slider from menucool.com
It appears it doesn't have a responsive folder.